# The process of creating Android layout files

Tags: android, android-layout

I am in the process of creating layouts for a new application and I am interested to know how you are usually approach this process.

Obviously it's a very general question, but I think we can get a lot of ideas from different developers' perspectives. As creating perfect layouts in Android, in my opinion, is one of the most difficult tasks in the app development process, I think the answers can be of value.

The assumption is that we want to support all device sizes with the least number of XML files, without compromising the application design quality.

In my case the designer of the app designed it with Galaxy S3 dimensions in mind (720 x 1280px).

Considering the 3:4:6:8 ratio -

1. What will be the base device you'll do the design for, so one layout file will look        good on all normal size devices?
2. How would you handle the difference in device dimensions, thinking in dp -

Eg.

```
   480 X 800 hdpi = 320 X 533dp
   320 X 480 mdpi = 320 X 480dp
   720 x 1280 xhdpi = 360 X 640dp
```

How will you still use the extra dp, so there won't be to many empty spaces, without making the layout not appropriate for 320 X 480 device?

1. When the designer marks a margin of 20px, how would you interpret it in the xml? 
   Taking into consideration he designed it on a 720 x 1280px canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with some screen size as your base target device for e.g. 4.7 inch (hdpi) and create a single layout for default screens in layout folder and declare dimensions in `dimens.xml` in values folder.

Next, let's say you want your layouts for a  7" device, create values-sw320dp folder for 7" in portrait orientation and declare separate dimensions in `dimens.xml` in this folder.

Next, let's say you want your layouts for a  10" device, create values-sw720dp folder for 10" in portrait orientation and declare separate dimensions in `dimens.xml` in this folder.

PS: For landscape orientation, add `-land` in the end of folder names.

Next, let's say you have new devices such as `xhdpi` and `xxhdpi` devices, you can create values-xhdpi and values-xxhdpi folders.

Since you have defined dimensions in `values` folder, when you run the App, most of the dimensions will be used from here only. And you can add/update the dimensions in respective folders for screen-size and resolutions on which there is any mismatch.

Also, if you have got separate drawables for various size like `mdpi`, `hdpi`, etc you can place them under `drawable-mdpi`, `drawable-hdpi`, etc.

The Android system will take care of loading correct resources at run-time.

**Note:** On Android versions < **3.2**, the folder naming was little different, you can refer that [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Android automatically scales layouts to fit the current device. One way to make the solution more elegant would be to create separate folders drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi and drawable-xxhdpi to hold the drawable resources - this is to make sure the same resource does not get used across all the different resolutions where it might not be so clear.
Do not use px (pixels) for measurements in the layout file - use dip (or density independent pixels) which allows to scale according to device pixel density.
The other extreme would be to have different layouts for different resolutions though this is is not advisable.